# android app crashing while sending Message to a list of 50 people

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My android application crashes while sending Message to a list of 50 people.
Anyone knows why this is happening then please do let me know.

```
  public class SendSMS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

private ArrayList<SearchResults>  list;
private String message;


public SendSMS(ArrayList<SearchResults> obj,String msg){
    this.list=obj;
    this.message=msg;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String sms=message;
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(sms);

     for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){


        Log.d("ListPhoneNumbers....", list.get(i).getPhoneNumber());




        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(list.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), null, parts, null, null);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();









    return null;
}




     }
```

Comment: Add the log in your question for more clarity

Comment: It does'nt show anything in log as i am testing app on phone. App sends messages to 50 people list but it suddenly crashes while sending messages..

Comment: Yes, but you should have a debug log in Eclipse/Android IDE? How can you expect to debug without a log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Toast message should be in runonui thread. You cant update the UI inside Async Task directly..

Comment: Its at the end of doInBackground() of an AsyncTask.  It shouldn't be in a runOnUIThread, it should be in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

You should add some more details to the question. In particular:

> LogCat
>
> Piece of code involved

EDIT: try this

```
public class SendSMS extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {

    private ArrayList < SearchResults > list;
    private String message;
    private Object context;


    public SendSMS(ArrayList < SearchResults > obj, String msg, Object context) {
        this.list = obj;
        this.message = msg;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String sms = message;
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList < String > parts = smsManager.divideMessage(sms);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Log.d("ListPhoneNumbers....", list.get(i).getPhoneNumber());

            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(list.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), null, parts, null, null);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "SMS Sent!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

that you call from the main UI in this way:

```
(new SendSMS(/*PARAMS*/)).execute(this);
```

Comment: Without knowing the error, I would suggest parameterized the AsyncTask, which is currently raw type. Secondly, don't return null: it can very easly throw a NPE.

Comment: Nothing wrong with returning null, especially in that situation-  you're returning a Void, the only valid Void is null.  That's what you're supposed to do if onPostExecute doesn't need to process a result.